# Use dynamic list in DropDownButton | Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dynamic, dropdownbutton

my problem is following:

```
class Data {
  final String? image, title, link;
  final Color? color;

  Data({
    this.title,
    this.image,
    this.link,
    this.color,
  });
}


List dataList = [
  Data(
      title: "XXX",
      image: "XXX",
      link: "XXX",
      color: XXX),

...
```

I have this class and list to store my data and however I'm used that way the first time to learn something new. Now I have the problem that I'm totally failing to create a DropDownButton with the data from my list because of the Data() I've in there.

I tried something like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          items: dataList.map((Map map) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: map["title"].toString(),
                child: new Text(
                  map["name"],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I was sure that this option wont work for my example. I think there is now way out to ask you for help. So my exact question is, how can I create a DropDownMenu/Button, where the title of all my Data classes is displayed in a list. I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: you want to get data from API and display it into dropdown?

Comment: I want to display each title of my Data item from my dataList in that dropdownmenu. See that in the first code section. So there should be displayed that "XXX" from each title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is of generic type Data, but you are treating it as a Map.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          items: dataList.map((data) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: data.title.toString(),
                child: Text(
                  data.name,
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It should work now.